# Sign android app from the command line on mac m1

Tags: gradlew, gradle-wrapper

I want to be able to run `./gradlew signingReport` from my command line to get the key signing for my apps. However I've had to reset my computer and forgot how this is accomplished. I've already made an upload keystore file. However when I run `./gradlew signingReport` I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'signingReport' not found in root project 'juliapak' and its subprojects.

* Try:
> Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 320ms
```